# Bad Type On Operand Stack error when using switch statement with double

Tags: java

The following program compiles without any errors, but when I run it, I get a java.lang.VerifyError

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 1;
        switch (d) {
            case 0.0: System.out.println("The value is zero");
            case 1.0: System.out.println("The value isn't zero");
            default: System.out.println("It's something else");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the complete error:

```
Exception Details:
  Location:
    Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @3: tableswitch
  Reason:
    Type double_2nd (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to integer
  Current Frame:
    bci: @3
    flags: { }
    locals: { '[Ljava/lang/String;', double, double_2nd }
    stack: { double, double_2nd }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 0f48 27aa 0000 0025 0000 0000 0000 0001
    0000010: 0000 0015 0000 001d b200 1012 16b6 0018
    0000020: b200 1012 1eb6 0018 b200 1012 20b6 0018
    0000030: b1
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@24,Double)
    same_frame(@32)
    same_frame(@40)
```

Does this mean `switch` statements cannot be used at all on `double`s? When I try the same code but using an `int` instead of a `double` it works as it should.
(using Java 17 in VSCode 1.6.4 on Windows 10 64 bit)

Comment: I came across this one too, but it's from ten years ago and they changed a lot since then concerning switch statements. Nowadays you should even be able to do sth like switch(Object), but I'm still struggling with the basics

Comment: The reason why `double` doesn't (and shouldn't) work is because the inexact nature of floating point precision makes it impossible to evaluate the cases. This precision problem does not exist with `int`.

Comment: This should not compile.  Using a `double` in a `switch` is not allowed.  If your compiler didn't complain, get a different JDK.

Comment: @TylerLiu alright thank you. imo (even though of course floating points numbers are very precise and so checking for equality usually doesn't make much sense) it should still be allowed, but I'll accept it. In my actual program, I was only checking for NaN and the two inifinities anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in double representation in computer. Floating point are not very good for switch.
For example even this if would not work in Java:
`if(0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3)`

If you really need to compare them, you can use something called `threshold comparison method`. Where you do something like this:

```
double epsilon = 0.000000000000001d;
if(Math.abs(d1 - 0.0) < epsilon) {
     System.out.println("The value is zero");
}
else if(Math.abs(d1 - 1.0) < epsilon) {
     System.out.println("The value isn't zero");
}
else {
     System.out.println("It's something else");
}
```

If you dont like this solution, you can try to look at https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparing-doubles there are more solutions.